# If $A=B\cup C$ and A is infinite so is B or C. Is there a better proof then this?

Tags: set-theory

I use only Dedekind's definition.
Is there a better then this:

if $f:A\rightarrow A$  is 1-1 and non-surjective then there's $x \in A\setminus f(A)$. let's define $x(0)=x$ and $x(n+1)=f(x(n))$.
D is the image of f.

Clearly the $x(n)$'s are all different. Wlog for every $n$ there's $m>n$ s.t $m\in B$.

Define a partial g on B intersection with D. $g(x(n))=x(k)$ where $k>n$ is minimal s.t. $x(k)  \in B$.
Now extend g using Id.
G is the witness that B is infinite.

Comment: This is totally reasonable... I'm curious, what is the context of your question?  You're using somewhat "advanced" vocabulary for the "level" of this question (no offense is meant).

Comment: @nomen You have put the finger on it. I expected the proof to be more trivial. Less inductive.

Comment: I mean, the contrapositive is fairly straightforward. If the union of two finite sets is finite.

Comment: @AsafKaragila how is it trivial using Dedekind definition?

Comment: Right. You need an intermediate lemma: Dedekind-finite iff "there is no countably infinite subset". Then such subset will be split into $B$ and $C$, and one of them needs to be infinite.

Comment: This is actually what happens in my proof. Is there a totally different approach? Or an example for a world where this fails?

Comment: I mean the claim and/or the lemma from Asaf's comment.

Comment: What do you mean "this fails"? This proof uses very little, if at all.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I think he means he can't think of a proof of your lemma without using basically the same "induction" argument in that context.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I mean a model without this induction principle. I think that you refered somewhere to a model with an infinite set with only finite subsets. Do you have a link for this?

Comment: No. I don't know much about models where induction fails, moreover this seems like a particularly simple formula so you might need to have induction fail *completely*, and I don't know about such set theories. And for an infinite set to exist without any infinite subsets, well, you need to not have subsets for $\varphi(x,y)$ defined by $x\neq y$. This is again one of the simplest formulas you can have. Maybe some kind of positive set theory, but I honestly don't know anything about those.